# calling from a *.lib c++

Tags: c++, .lib

Could someone please tell me how to call this type of function from a lib file (I got this from `dumpbin /list`) 
here it is:
 `00A 00000000 SECT4  notype       External     | ?GetWindowPauseOnSizeMove_ext@@3P6G_NXZA (bool (__stdcall* GetWindowPauseOnSizeMove_ext)(void))`

I've tried

```
#pragma comment( lib, "MyLib" )
 extern "C" bool _stdcall GetWindowPauseOnSizeMove_ext(void)
```

But I Get this error

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> ```
>
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _GetWindowPauseOnSizeMove_ext@0 referenced in function _Test NF_dll  D:\Test\Test\main.obj   1

Any help will be great

Comment: I don't know the answer, but one way to figure it out would be to take the signature you think should match, and compile it yourself into a library.  Then you can see what ends up in a library you build, and see how it differs from the one you're trying to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the parameter mangling in the `dumpbin` list, it appears that the function has been actually compiled as C++.

Try to remove the `extern "C"`, and try to play with the calling convention (`__stdcall`, `_cdecl`, `__fastcall`).

---

If the http://demangler.com/ is correct, the function signature should be:

```
BOOL __stdcall GetWindowPauseOnSizeMove_ext(void)
```

I.e. close to what you have, only with the C++ linkage instead of the C linkage.

Comment: Great Thanks wish I knew about that site before  :D